# Не работает ScrollView с ImageView?

Tags: android

Всем привет. Есть такая разметка.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_x="0px"
            android:layout_y="25px"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:onClick="click_img"

                android:id="@+id/artist_img" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:shadowColor="#cccccc"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
           />
        </ScrollView>
```

Хочу что бы изображение и textview были в одном scrollview что бы листать и текст и изображения. Но выкидывает и выдает ошибку.

```
Binary XML file line #39
```

Если вывести ImageView За пределы ScrollView то все работает нормально!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин задал вопрос и сразу же нашел ответ.

"Как сказано в документации, ScrollView — это FrameLayout, а это значит, что он может содержать только один дочерний элемент. Обычно этим элементом является какой-то LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией, который содержит все остальные элементы экрана."

Comment: ScrollView может содержать только один дочерний элемент, FrameLayout сколько угодно.